# change size of special character

Tags: fontsize

the normal % character is a little bit bigger than numbers so I want to reduce its size by the command `{\small }`. I tried it with the command `\renewcommand{\%}{{\small \%}}` but that produces the error: `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [grouping levels=255] \%`
It's possible to solve it by entering `\newcommand{\test}{{\small \%}}` but that leaves me to change the expression in around 30 documents with a possibility of making an error myself.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\%}{{\small \%}}
\begin{document}

\%
{\small \%}

(1\%)
(1{\small \%})

\end{document}
```

An example of the bad looking % charakter (done by changing one command to `%\renewcommand{\%}{{\small \%}}`:

[image: example of %-size]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want a solution suitable for all sizes you can try (requires `graphicx` package)

```
\let\oldpercent\%
\renewcommand{\%}{\scalebox{0.85}{\oldpercent}}
```

[image]

MWE to generate the example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\oldpercent\%
\renewcommand{\%}{\scalebox{0.85}{\oldpercent}}

\begin{document}

\tiny 1\%

\scriptsize 1\%

\footnotesize 1\%

\small 1\%

\normalsize 1\%

\large 1\%

\Large 1\%

\LARGE 1\%

\huge 1\%

\Huge 1\%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @David. Without your packages half of the things we can do with TeX wouldn't be doable... :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
\let\oldpercent\%
\renewcommand{\%}{{\small \oldpercent}}
```

But note this only does the right thing at normal size, it will always use `\small` even if the current size is `\huge`.

Comment: I suppose one could cater to the fact that the surrounding text might not be set in "normalsize" by loading the `relsize` package and setting `\renewcommand{\%}{{\smaller \oldpercent}}`... :-)